# Passen zu, auf oder für?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied bei den drei Präpositionen *zu*, *auf* und *für* mit dem Verb *passen*, oder sind sie austauschbar? Z. B. in den Sätzen unten scheinen alle drei Präpositionen mit dem Verb dem englischen *to fit something* zu entsprechen.

> - Das passt nicht **zu** Harrys Profil.
> - Das passt nicht **auf** das Profil eines typischen Straßenräubers.
> - Scheint passend **für** einen Polizistenmörder zu sein.

Comment: Kartoffelbrei passt gut *zu* Rotkohl, aber eher nicht so gut *auf* selbigen...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, hier ein Versuch von meiner Seite:
*Passen zu* ist wohl die häufigste Verwendung. Mit *zu* wird ein Vergleich angedeutet. In deinem Beispiel vergleicht man "*das*"(wofür es auch stehen möge) mit "*Harrys Profil*". Weiteres Beispiel: "Dieser Kristall passt nicht *zu* den anderen."(*auf* und *für* können hier nicht verwendet werden.

*Passen für* wird genutzt bei Dingen die sich entsprechend verhalten, z.B. "Diese Reaktion ist passend für diese Art von Gestein."(Kann nicht durch "zu" ersetzt werden). Es kann fast immer durch "entsprechen" ersetzt werden. -> "Das entspricht dem Profil eines Straßenräubers."

*Passen auf* kenne ich nur in Verbindung mit "Profil" oder gleichbedeutenden Worte (z.B. Verhaltensmuster, Kodex, etc.). Es ist sinnhaft gleichbedeutend mit *passen für*.

Technisch gesehen könnte man alle drei deiner Beispiele nutzen, jedoch würde ich zu "auf" tendieren.

Comment: Du kennst sicher auch "Der Helm passt auf den Kopf, der Deckel auf den Topf und die Faust auf's Auge".